# Missing Document Providers using Intent.ActionCreateDocument

Tags: android-activity, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-document-provider

When I use `Intent.ActionOpenDocument` as the activity the resulting picker shows all available document providers. When I use `Intent.ActionCreateDocument` the resulting picker shows a limited subset of document providers. Does anyone know of a method to have the `Intent.ActionCreateDocument` picker show all document providers?

[image: ActionOpenDocument]
[image: ActionCreateDocument]

Comment: What is the version of your device?

Comment: App Min version is 9(28) target version is 10(29) test device is 10(29).

Comment: I have Intent.ActionCreateDocument working as expected with DropBox and Google Drive. Have not been able to get OneDrive available under this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When OneDrive app is installed it support `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Intent (`Android Storage Access Framework (SAF)`), but unfortunately it does not support `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` intent from the same `SAF`.Thus we can implement work-around: 1st invoke `ACTION_SEND` and latter `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

**But** this means bad user experience for end user when interacting with OneDrive comparing to doing same action with Google Drive (which support both open and create intents.) As result user would need to select file twice using OneDrive and only once if he use GDrive.

Comment: Thank you Leon for the info. Just had the opportunity to review the suggestion. I'll give that a test.
I wonder why MS doesn't support ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT for OneDrive, and who should get the earful:)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SEND